# Spring Boot MVC default IllegalArgumentException mapping to HTTP response codes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, illegalargumentexception

Does Spring Boot MVC by default map `IllegalArgumentException` to an HTTP response code? (I was surprised that I couldn't find it in `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` nor in a search here on Stack Overflow.)

Secondly how would I override or configure that mapping? (I'm familiar with how to do it in JAX-RS.)